# Learning C trying to figure out this malloc stuff via functions

Tags: c, arrays, memory, valgrind

Hey I'm trying to figure out why the following code gets invalid write of size error from Valgrind at the line: `array[i-1] = I;`

I really don't now why my allocate_array function doesn't work. I tried so many things.

There are couple errors more but I just wanted to check first why this line is false or why my array isn't allocated.

Hope you can help me to figure out my error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//Programm to check Gaussian function

int read_number_from_stdin(int* value) {
  printf("Number for the Gaussian Function: ");
  int return_value = scanf("%d", value);
  if (return_value == 0) {
    while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n')
      ;
  }
  if (return_value == EOF) {
    return_value = 0;
  }
  return return_value;
}

int read_number_from_string(char* string, int* value) {
  printf("Reading input...\n");
  int return_value = sscanf(string, "%d", value);
  if (return_value == 0 || return_value == EOF) {
    printf("\t... Error your input is not a Number!\n");
    return_value = 0;
  } else {
    printf("\t... Number %d read and saved.\n", *value);
  }
  return return_value;
}

int* allocate_array(int* size) //allocating memory for the array
{
  int* result = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * (*size));
  return result;
}

void initialize_array(int array[], int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    array[i] = i+1;
  }
}

int compute_sum_and_place_in_first_elem(int array[], int* size) {

  int sum_array = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
    sum_array += array[i];
  }

return sum_array;

}

void free_memory(int array[], int* N) {
  free(array);
  free(N);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int* N = malloc(sizeof(int));
  if (argc == 1) {
    while (read_number_from_stdin(N) != 1)
      ;
  } else if (argc == 2) {
    if (read_number_from_string(argv[1], N) == 0) {
      printf("Error: No valid number!\n", argv[1]);
      return -1;
    }
  } else {
    printf("No valid number!\n");
    return -1;
  }

  int* array = allocate_array(N); //allocate via function

  initialize_array(array, *N); //initialize the array up to n



  int result = compute_sum_and_place_in_first_elem(array, N); 

  int result_gauss = ((*N + 1) * (*N) / 2);
  if (result == result_gauss) {
    printf("Gauss was right your calculations match with his function");
  } else {
    printf(
        "\nGauss was not right!\n" 
        "The summ of %d is %d and therefore not equal to(%d+1)*%d/2\n\n",
        *N, result, *N, *N);
  }

  //free memory
  free_memory(array, N);
}
```

Comment: Think about `array[i-1]` when `i` equals 0.

Comment: Then take a look at `free_memory` that *starts* with a `return`. How are we going to reach the `free`-calls?

Comment: Note that `while (fgetc(stdin) != '\n');` is an infinite loop on end-of-file.

Comment: note that `i <= size` always rings an alarm for an experienced C coder. 99% of the time you mean `i < size`. Reminder: an array with 3 entries has indexes 0,1,2

Comment: BTW - +1 for using valgrind

Comment: @Richie: The code you're showing is not the code you're running. There is a `+I++` in there that shouldn't even compile. And changing the code in the question around invalidates any previous answers; this shouldn't happen. Try to make the question about a *single specific* problem, and provide a [mcve] -- the focus being on "minimal", so answers don't get sidetracked by "other errors".

Comment: So if I correct my code with the help of the answers and still get a memory leak - like happened - how can I ask further why there is still a problem after solving everything people was telling me. As I answered down. I understand what you were saying thank you for the help.

Comment: You shouldn't just correct the code in your question, as now the answer doesn't make sense any more. You could instead add a paragraph where you put your update, or, if the new problem you are facing is completely different, you should open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see, for the `initialize_array()` function, for the `for` loop, very first iteration, `i` is `0`, and you're executing

```
   array[i-1] = i;
```

which translates to

```
   array [-1] = ....
```

which is illegal.

You can fix that using the default C-array property of 0-based indexing scheme. Something like

```
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = i;
    }
```

Comment: Note also the change from `for (int i = 0; i <= size; ++i)` to `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)` to avoid writing beyond the end of the array, too.

Comment: as you see I changed everything. I still get following Valgrind error:        LEAK SUMMARY:
==3995==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3995==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3995==      possibly lost: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==3995==    still reachable: 200 bytes in 6 blocks
==3995==         suppressed: 21,894 bytes in 154 blocks
==3995== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.